# How can i run the asset studio master in desktop?

Tags: icons, assets

I want to run this in my system and see how it works.

https://github.com/romannurik/AndroidAssetStudio

I downloaded it from there and installed the node, npm,gulp and bower components. Couldnt figureout how to link to this files.

How can i use these files to make it a desktop app or to make it work offline.

link for the icon generator.
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/
Can someone help me how to make this work.

Thanks.

Comment: You must be more specific in your question. Please write up a detailed problem description. Also verify that you got the right tags, just because you got the files from github doesn't make it a git question so make sure to verify what it really is.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  i want to make it work offline , is there any possibility i can do that.